# How many bolts can Apache Storm handle?

Tags: java, apache-storm

Following is my sample storm topology,

```
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("EventSpout", new TenderEventSpout2(), 1);

    builder.setBolt("CleanseLoadBolt", new CleanseLoadBolt(), 1).shuffleGrouping("EventSpout");

    builder.setBolt("EventGeneratorBolt", new EventGeneratorBolt(), 1).shuffleGrouping("CleanseLoadBolt");

    builder.setBolt("Event1Bolt", new Event1Bolt(), 1)
        .shuffleGrouping("EventGeneratorBolt","stream1");

    builder.setBolt("Event2Bolt", new Event2Bolt(), 1)
        .shuffleGrouping("EventGeneratorBolt","stream2");

    builder.setBolt("Event3Bolt", new Event3Bolt(), 1)
        .shuffleGrouping("EventGeneratorBolt","stream3");

    builder.setBolt("Rule1Bolt", new Rule1Bolt(), 1)
        .shuffleGrouping("Event1Bolt","stream1")
        .shuffleGrouping("Event3Bolt","stream1");

    builder.setBolt("Rule2Bolt", new Rule2Bolt(), 1)
        .shuffleGrouping("Event1Bolt","stream2")
        .shuffleGrouping("Event2Bolt","stream2");

    builder.setBolt("DBBolt", new DBBolt(), 1)
        .shuffleGrouping("Rule1Bolt")
        .shuffleGrouping("Rule2Bolt");//.shuffleGrouping("EventProcessorBolt");

    return builder.createTopology();`
```

Currently, I have 3 event bolts and 2 rule bolts. But according to my requirement, it might go beyond 20 for events and rules as well. Is it a good way to design systems like this? Or is there any better approach to design this in storm?

Comment: Storm can easily handle this number of bolt. It is deployed in larger production clusters with many hundreds of node.

Comment: This presentation is a bit old but has good info http://www.slideshare.net/ptgoetz/scaling-apache-storm-strata-hadoopworld-2014

Answer (score 1):

In [CakeLabs](http://www.cakelabs.lk/) currently we are executing Storm typologies with 40 bolts and it is running in production more than 1 and half year.
But Performance will be depend on storm cluster size. 
if your deploying a 40 bolts cluster you will required a 4 node storm cluster to get the best performance.

40 bolts -> 80 executors -> 8 workers -> 4 servers